# How to render React Component Once then update afterwards for Chessboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Intro

I am working on building a chess application using React.js.

[image]

Currently I am struggling with how to change the state of a child component based on the state of the parent component. This function specifically deals with 2 components

1. Board
2. Tile

Here is a rough outline of how they are being used

`Board.js`

```js
class Board extends React.Component {
    state = {
        selected: ''
    }

 // select a tile based on event.target clicks
   selectTile = event => {
        let { id } = event.target;
        this.setState({
            selected: id
        })
     }

// This is how I create the board initially with all the piece on it
// this is only a small segment of the entire function. I have removed several items for clarity
   createBoard = () => {
       let board = [];
       let rowID = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
         for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            let row = [];

            // Tiles
            for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                // If the row num is 0 or even
                if (i === 0 || i % 2 === 0) {

                    // If tile is even
                    if (j % 2 === 0) {
                        row.push(<Tile
                            select={this.selectTile}
                            color='white'
                            id={`${rowID[i]}${j + 1}`}
                            key={`${rowID[i]}${j + 1}`}
                            piece={rowID[i] === 'a' || rowID[i] === 'g' ? <Piece color={color[rowID[i]]} type='pawn' position={`${rowID[i]}${j + 1}`} /> : ''}
                        />)
                    } else {
                        row.push(<Tile
                            select={this.selectTile}
                            color='black'
                            id={`${rowID[i]}${j + 1}`}
                            key={`${rowID[i]}${j + 1}`}
                            piece={rowID[i] === 'a' || rowID[i] === 'g' ? <Piece color={color[rowID[i]]} type='pawn' position={`${rowID[i]}${j + 1}`} /> : ''}
                        />)
                    }

                     // additional conditionals go here but they are similar to the ones above

                } 
            }

            board.push(<div className='row' id={`${rowID[i]}`} key={`${rowID[i]}`}>{row}</div>)
        }

        return board
     }

     render() {
        {this.createBoard()}
 }
```

`Tile.js`

```js
class Tile extends React.Component {

    state = {
        selected: false,
        occupied: false,
        id: ''
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        // Check if a Piece was passed in as a prop
        if (this.props.piece) {
            this.setState({
                occupied: true
            })
        }

        this.setState({
            id: this.props.id
        })
    }

   // THE MAIN PROBLEM. I want to do something like this
   componentDidUpdate() {
      if (this.props.selected === this.state.id) {
              this.setState({
                  selected: true
            })  
       }     
}

    render() {
        let btn_class1 = this.state.selected ? 'tile-white selected' : 'tile-white'
        let btn_class2 = this.state.selected ? 'tile-black selected' : 'tile-black'

        // If a piece is passed in as a prop
        // It should only change color if it has been selected on the state of Chess
        if (this.state.occupied === true) {

            if (this.props.color === 'white') {
                return (
                    <div className={btn_class1} id={this.props.id} onClick={this.props.select}>
                        {this.props.piece}
                    </div>
                )
            } else {
                return (
                    <div className={btn_class2} id={this.props.id} onClick={this.props.select}>
                        {this.props.piece}
                    </div>
                )
            }

            // If the tile is not occupied. Other functions go here
        } 
    }
}

export default Tile;
```

### The Problem

What works right now is that I can change the state of `selected` in the `Board` component, but I now need to figure out how to pass that value of `this.state.selected` to the `Tile` component to check if it is the one that is selected.

If you have any suggestions or questions for clarification please feel free to let me know. Thank you!

Comment: If the board holds the state of the pieces, then when the board is updated and child tiles should be re-rendered. Check out lifting state up https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Maybe maintain a array of the pieces in the board component - then just update that array

Answer (score 0):

If you can get correct id value of a Tile in `selectTile` function in Board, you can simply pass a boolean `selected` to Tile like

```
let id = `${rowID[i]}${j + 1}`;
row.push(<Tile
    select={this.selectTile}
    selected={this.state.seleccted===id}
    color='white'
    id={`${rowID[i]}${j + 1}`} ...
```

Then in `render` of Tile use `this.props.selected` instead of `this.state.selected`.
You only miss passing `selected` and use `this.props.selected`.